# Scaffolding ASP.NET dando erro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ado.net

O erro é gerado usando o VS 2012. Quando tento criar o Controller para as minhas News usando o Entity framework, já tentei de várias as formas. o Meu banco de dados vocês podem ver no server explorer a esquerda.

Estou tentando criar o controller para as CRUDS.

[image: erro VS]

"Unable to retrieve metadata for "BraveryBranded.ASP.Models.News". Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Você já compilou o projeto?

Comment: @AndréLeria sim

Comment: @LuizNegrini Aparentemente a abordagem é Database-First. Você consegue ver as tabelas através da sua conexão ao banco de dados ali no `Server Explorer`?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez consegui sim! MAs já vou informar que o erro era mesmo a pasta onde o model estava, eu tirei ele da "Area" Admin e coloquei na pasta model padrão criada pelo projeto e tudo funcionou! Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Ok, só peço para que marque no ícone verde sua resposta como aceita, em benefício a todos da comunidade. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema ocorreu por que a pasta model não era a padrão criada pelo VS. Eu havia deixado meus models dentro da 'Area' admin, por isto não funcionava.

Para resolver bastou mover para a pasta Model padrão e tentar usar o scaffolding novamente.

Comment: Isso resolveu e seu problema e é a resposta mais correta? Aceite ela para deixar marcado para todos.

Answer (score 0):

Já fez rebuild da sua aplicação ? se estiver fazendo scaffolding é preciso dar rebuild após alterar as propriedades de uma classe.

Comment: Sim, será que o problema não ocorre por que as classes usadas não estão na pasta de Models fora da pasta 'Areas'?

Comment: Certo, você conseguiu utilizar o scaffolding para qualquer outra classe? todas dão o mesmo erro? 
Caso nenhuma funcione verifique se a instalação do mvcscaffolding esta correta, veja como verificar:(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148914/cannot-add-a-mvc-controller-vs2012-gives-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instanc)

Comment: Realmente para nenhuma funciona.